# Join Three Tables and Use Count on One of Them

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to improve my querying abilities and I have been having trouble wrapping my head around joins of moderate complexity. To be as clear and concise as possible, I am trying to join 3 tables. The first join selects posts from all users on users.User_ID=posts.FK_User_ID

```
**User table**
User_ID pk
username int
email 
etc...

**Post Table**
post_ID PK
User_ID FK
Post
etc...

**Like Table**
FK_User_ID references user.user_ID
FK_Post_ID references post.Post_ID (*This is what I want to count*)
```

after this I want to reference a third table. This table contains a Foreign key to user_ID of user table and a foreign key of FK_Post_ID referencing the primary key Post_ID in the post table. This third table is a linking table of users who have liked the post. I want to count all occurrences of a post ID in this table and append it to each post in the initial user and post join so an output result would look like this:

```
    User_id   Username  Post_ID   Post     Number_of_Likes
     1         bob       4        'foo'     18
```

my first join between the two tables works and looks like this (simplified with * for example)

```
   select * from users
   join post
   on post.User_ID=users.User_ID
```

Now I need a way to reference the third table to count the total # of times that a post id appears in the like table and append it to each row. This is where I am lost, I have been trying a lot of things to no luck. I believe I need to construct an inner join clause for my second join or I need to pull off a nested select statement? Could someone correct me on this if I am wrong and perhaps guide me in the right direct? Appreciate it!

Comment: can you tag the dbms being used?

Comment: you either have to subquery to get the count from the 3rd table before the join, use a `count(Distinct Primary.keyField )` from the 3 table, or use a window function `count() over (partition by fields which make logical key)`  DBMS & Version would help define which options are available to you although the subquery will work in all RDBMS.

Comment: Consider posting table definitions and some sample data, in addition to the expected output.

Comment: as a note... you don't tell us the name of the 3rd table or any of the column names of that table.  This kind of omission can make a question hard to answer.

Comment: @Hogan added table structures, forgot the first time. Sorry about that and thank you for the comments

Comment: Why is your user table called "users" and your post table called post?  You should be consistent -- leading practice would be to not use the plural and have a tables named user, post.

Comment: @Murph_Fish -- you're welcome. as you can see I was able to answer the question.  Just change "likestable" to the name of your table with the likes votes in it.

Comment: In your code sample you show "post.FK_User_ID" but in your table structure it shows just "post.User_ID".  One of these is wrong.

Comment: @Hogan yeah my table names are inconsistent and I need to restructure. I am newish to database stuff and one of my constant pitfalls is accidentally pluralizing table names and attributes. I just read in a book last night not to do this and will keep in mind for the future. Thank you very much for your correct response. I am making a twitter clone and it has been a good challenge so far!

Comment: Sounds like a fun learning project, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to do this is make a sub-query that has counts and key then join to that.  Like this:

```
select * 
from users
join post on post.FK_User_ID=users.User_ID
left join (
   select  FK_Post_ID, count(*) as count_of_likes_on_a_post
   from likestable 
   group by FK_Post_ID
) likes on post.Post_ID = likes.FK_Post_ID
```